# Block syntax error from Apple example 'Creating a Block'

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Using [**apple's example**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxDeclaringCreating.html) from the docs

```
float (^oneFrom)(float);


oneFrom = ^(float aFloat) {

  float result = aFloat - 1.0;

  return result;

};
```

I get two errors:

1. Redefinition of 'oneFrom' with a different type: 'int' vs 'float(^)(float)'
2. Type specifier missing, defaults to 'int'

Also from the doc..

> If you don’t explicitly declare the return value of a block
>   expression, it can be automatically inferred from the contents of the
>   block. If the return type is inferred and the parameter list is void,
>   then you can omit the (void) parameter list as well. If or when
>   multiple return statements are present, they must exactly match (using
>   casting if necessary).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't define blocks on file scope, only in functions. This works as expected:

```
void foo (void)
{
    float (^oneFrom)(float);
    oneFrom = ^(float aFloat) {
        float result = aFloat - 1.0;
        return result;
    };
}
```

Comment: My understanding was that blocks are similar to C function pointers. Shouldn't I be able to declare it in the header file?

Comment: @estobbart No, blocks are a much more complex concept than function pointers. Most important: they carry data, so they have to be dynamically allocated on the stack or heap. C does not allow for initialization of objects with static storage duration, so you can't define a block on file scope.

Comment: @estobbart You can, of course, declare a block type variable using `extern` in a header file. You cannot define a block, though.

Comment: Understood. There's a number of examples of declaring a block. Is there a situation where a block declaration is used? It looks like blocks are almost always used as block literals.

Comment: One example would be a property of block type, for example `NSFileHandle`'s `readabilityHandler`.

Comment: how do I use the block if it is inside the function? how do i call it? I've been looking all over. Not easy to find lots of info on blocks

Answer (score -1):

that block doesnt have a return type, and the default return type is void, you will need to go

```
float (^oneFrom)(float);

oneFrom = ^ float (float aFloat) {

  float result = aFloat - 1.0;

  return result;

};
```

[here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html) is a better blocks example

Comment: This example still reports the same errors. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: No. The block has a return type which is deducted from the actual `return` statement. It has the correct type of `float`.

Comment: ah, yes my mistake, ive always implicitly done it for some reason. your answer is probably the real solution here as well, didnt think about where the block would be defined

Comment: @nikolai I think you mean "deduced" not "deducted". Perhaps "inferred" would be a better choice of words?